# using double quotes in bash export statement

Tags: bash

Hello I'm reading a book about bash scripting and the author says to add the following to the end of my .bashrc file.  `export PATH=~/bin:"$PATH"` in order to execute my file from the command line by typing its name.  I notice however that if I put `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` I can achieve the same result.  So my question is what is the difference between the one with quotes and the one without quotes?  thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must include the variable `PATH` inside double quotes. So that it would handle the filepaths which has spaces but without double quotes, it won't handle the filenames which has spaces in it.

Comment: The quotes aren't necessary, but they don't harm anything either. Try `foo="1 2"; export bar=$foo`. `bar` still gets the value `1 2`.

Comment: then add it as an answer. I'll delete mine.

Comment: This is a good rule for the general case -- it's just that assignments are special and don't string-split by default.

Answer (score 7):

The quotes won't hurt anything, but neither are they necessary. Assignments are processed specially by the shell. From the man page:

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> ```
>           name=[value]
> ```
>
> If value is not given, the variable is assigned the null string.  All values undergo **tilde expansion, parameter and variable
>   expansion, command  substitution,  arithmetic  expansion,  and
>          quote  removal**  (see  EXPANSION below).

Notice that word-splitting and pathname generation are not on the list in bold. These are the two types of expansion you are trying to prevent by quoting a parameter expansion, but in this context they are not performed. The same rules apply to the assignments that are passed to the `export` built-in command.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same with trying to assign a JSON string to a variable in the terminal.

**Wrap it with Single Quotes or Double Quotes**

Use single quotes, if you string contains double quotes and vice-versa.

```
$ export TEMP_ENV='I like the "London" bridge'
$ echo $TEMP_ENV
>> I like the "London" bridge


$ export TEMP_ENV="I like the 'London' bridge"
$ echo $TEMP_ENV
>> I like the 'London' bridge
```